# How do I remove "Allow unauthenticated" from a HTTP onRequest Gen 2 Firebase Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, firebase-tools

When deploying functions with `gcloud` we can use the flag `--no-allow-unauthenticated` to stop functions from being accessed by anyone.

That flag does not exist for Firebase. For example, this does NOT work:

`firebase deploy --only functions --no-allow-unauthenticated`

So currently when I deploy a HTTP onRequest Gen 2 Firebase Function it automatically deploys with "Allow unauthenticated" authentication status. This is bad. How do I stop that from happening?

I want to either remove the "Allow unauthenticated" status after deploying, or avoid deploying like that in the first place.

Note: This is for Gen 2 Firebase Functions. I can't find anything applicable to that. With Gen 1 all I have to do is remove "allUsers" role but Gen 2 functions do not have that role and they are still marked as "Allow unauthenticated".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase CLI can't do it. The default is to allow access because most Firebase developers use Cloud Functions to deploy web APIs that should be accessible publicly as part of their applications.

You can use gcloud to modify the permissions after deployment.  The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment) covers adding permissions, with specific instructions for 2nd gen functions.  You can remove the permission by using `remove-iam-policy-binding` instead of `add-iam-policy-binding`.

```
gcloud run services remove-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION_NAME \
  --member="allUsers" \
  --role="roles/run.invoker"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! But you might want to edit the sample code block so that it uses `remove-iam-policy-binding` so people don't get confused.